# Scroll to end to grid UI-Grid Angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to scroll to end of the grid when data is loaded. But the code is not working. Please help

```
$scope.addData = function () {
        var n = $scope.gridOptions.data.length + 1;
        $scope.gridOptions.data.push({
                     "type":"student",
                    "is_job_ready":"true",
                     "is_night_shift":"true"
                 });
    $scope.scrollTo($scope.gridOptions.data.length -1,0)
    };

$scope.scrollTo = function( rowIndex, colIndex ) {
        $scope.gridApi.core.scrollTo( $scope.gridOptions.data[rowIndex],$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[colIndex]);
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to include this module into your js code:

`ui.grid.cellNav`

Then, this scroll is going to work:

`$scope.gridApi.core.scrollTo($scope.gridOptions.data[$scope.gridOptions.data.length - 1], $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[0]);`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it seems it is still necessary to use `$timeout`

For example

```
$timeout(function () {
    // Do this after the columns and rows processors have finished and it is all rendered.
    $scope.gridApi.core.scrollTo($scope.gridOptions.data[$scope.gridOptions.data.length - 1], $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[0]);
}, 100);
```

This is even after I tried waiting on modifyRows like this in my code

```
gridApi.grid.modifyRows(list).then(function () {
    // Do this after the columns and rows processors have finished and it is all rendered.
    gridApi.selection.selectRow(list[rowIndex]);
    gridApi.core.scrollTo(list[rowIndex], grid.columnDefs[0]);
});
```